# height: 100% is not working on div element

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  /* height: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

My big problem is that in the css, if I add height: 100%; attribute to .container, it will just have the height of whatever content is in the child divs. However if I use height: 100vh; for some reason it works.

How can I make it work with percentages?

What's the explanation to the problem?

Comment: Change the body from `min-height` to `height`. Read about the containing block at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block